# How to differentiate between writing an introduction and a conclusion?

Tags: writing-advice

I know this sounds silly but bear with me. In the introduction, I state my thesis and briefly point out the ideas to follow. In a conclusion, I re-state the ideas that I have discussed in the body. I always find myself writing the same stuff as an introduction and the conclusion. How would I clearly differentiate between the two?

Comment: They are, weirdly, similar. The conclusion can assume _some_ knowledge of what has gone on before.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing advice

Comment: This question is off-topic for EL&U, but you may be able to get an answer on [writers.se]. You should also include some concrete examples of what you have included in your introductions and conclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explore, expand, and alter your assertions a bit. I've thrown in an introduction and conclusion in italics.

In your intro, you state your thesis. *Intro: In an essay, one's introduction, body, and conclusion differ in their approach toward your thesis.*

In your body, you state your problem and provide assertions that strengthen your thesis. You may also explore alternatives to your thesis (perhaps an opposing point of view) and show how they are weaker than your thesis. *Body: An introduction states your thesis, which at this point is unproven in the reader's mind. Then you "prove your point" by providing logical arguments that support your thesis.*

In your conclusion, you say that your thesis has been proven or is stronger than the alternatives. You would like to leave the reader with the sense that you have proven what you set out to prove in your thesis statement.

So while the intro will always state your thesis, the conclusion helps the reader conclude that your thesis was correct. *Conclusion: In conclusion, one may see that the conclusion draws the reader's attention back to your thesis statement, which has been proven in the course of the essay.*